# Check if row is grouped in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Simple question I guess, how do I check if the row was grouped in a while loop. I want to be able to determine if it was grouped so I can change the text that is echoed if it is grouped but keep the rows that aren't grouped the same. I hope that this makes sense as I am not sure how else to explain it.

This is the code I have

```
if($r['type'] == "Wall"){
$offern = $r['aff'];
}else{
$offern = $offn['name'];
}
//  IF GROUPED $r['user_id'] <- It is grouped by `user_id` -> $offern = "Several";

print "<tr>
<td></td>
                <td><a href='lockedf.php?id=".$r['user_id']."'>{$namess['username']}</a></td>
                <td>".$offern."</td>
                <td>{$r['point']} Points</td>
                <td>".date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", $r['date_submitted'])."</td>
                <td><a href='unlock.php?id={$r['id']}' class='ask'><img src='images/unlock.png' alt='' title='' border='0' /></a></td>
                <td><a href='deny.php?id={$r['id']}' class='ask'><img src='images/trash.png' alt='' title='' border='0' /></a></td>
                </tr>";
```

Comment: You could add a `COUNT(some column other than user_ID)` to the query. The count will tell you how many records were grouped. And if the COUNT() column is greater than 1, then do what you need to.

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick to the main query? or to create a new one o.O

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick forget that last comment I figured out what you meant, can you post that as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you had data like this:

```
`USER_ID`  |  `FavoriteCandy`

1        |   'Snickers'
1        |   'Butterfinger'
2        |   'Hershey'
3        |   'Twix'
```

And a query like this:

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM tbl
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

And your goal was to figure out which user (user 1 in this case) might be missing candy because it was grouped on...you could do this:

```
SELECT `USER_ID`, COUNT(`FavoriteCandy`)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

Or, limit it to just users who are grouped like this:

```
SELECT `USER_ID`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY USER_ID
HAVING COUNT(`FavoriteCandy`) > 1;
```